# Is it allowed to Substring IPHostEntry.HostName for Machine Name?

Tags: c#, dns, hostname, reverse-dns

Right now i have the requirement to find some PC's Hostname by his IP Address and i solved this problem with this function:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the DNS Name of IP Address without the Domain.
/// </summary>
public string GetDNSNameFromReverseLookUp(string ip)
{
    IPAddress hostIPAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
    IPHostEntry hostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostIPAddress);
    return hostInfo.HostName.Substring(0, hostInfo.HostName.IndexOf('.'));
}
```

But i'm not happy with this `substring()` solution of the problem.

Is it allowed to use this function this way? Or do i have to fear some **network** issues in the future? Are there better (more secure) ways to get to the hostname without domain?

*I'm looking for an more network secure solution, not another way to handle strings. As mentioned in the comments I fear a little bit, that not every OS returns the Hostname in the format:`[Hostname].[Domainname]`.*

Comment: The other way could be to split the string on dot(.) but that would be only as SECURE as this one :)

Comment: Why do you think that this approach is not secure?

Comment: I fear a little bit, that not every OS returns the Hostname in the format: `[Hostname].[Domainname]`.

Answer (score 0):

You will get an error if pc are not joined to a domain. Since the (dot) is not found, and so the use of split function is the most reasonable. I've already checked.

Comment: That's right but also not the responsibility of the function.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
public string GetDNSNameFromReverseLookUp(string ip)
{
    IPAddress hostIPAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
    IPHostEntry hostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostIPAddress);
    return hostInfo.HostName.Split('.')[0];
}
```